# MySQL query to get a list of records depending on year/month/day

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to get count of the records from my database which has happened in a specific day which is in the table. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  count(id),
  A.status,
  YEAR(A.dateRequested),
  MONTHNAME(A.dateRequested),
  WEEK(A.dateRequested),
  DAYNAME(A.dateRequested)
FROM ASSESSMENT A where A.status = 'Pending';
```

What it gives me is just one record:

```
50  Pending 2013    April   16  Monday
```

Why it is not giving me all the records listed. For e.g. I have 50 records inserted on Monday, I have 20 on Tuesday and so on.. How can I get the list like that? And why the function WEEK(A.dateRequested) returns `16` as there are 4 weeks in a month?

Comment: Week gives you the week of the year, not of the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `count(id)` without a `group by`.  The way MySQL works is that this translates to an empty `group by`.  You'll get the `count(id)` for the entire table, and the other fields will be set to one random row.

To list the number of Pending records by weekday:

```
SELECT  DAYNAME(A.dateRequested)
,       count(id),
FROM    ASSESSMENT A 
where   A.status = 'Pending'
group by
        DAYNAME(A.dateRequested)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Week 16 is the week of the year, not the week of the month.
2. Your query is NOT querying for items happened today. It is looking for items which have a pending status. Change it to something like:

   WHERE A.dateRequested = '2013-06-20'
3. You are using COUNT function which will return only one result unless you GROUP BY something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT
  count(id),
  A.status,
  YEAR(A.dateRequested),
  MONTHNAME(A.dateRequested),
  WEEK(A.dateRequested),
  DAYNAME(A.dateRequested)
FROM ASSESSMENT A where A.status = 'Pending'
GROUP BY A.status,
  YEAR(A.dateRequested),
  MONTHNAME(A.dateRequested),
  WEEK(A.dateRequested),
  DAYNAME(A.dateRequested)
```

Comment: Why did you put A.status into the group by?

Comment: It is a field being returned. If it has a single value for the date then having it in the GROUP BY will make no difference. If there are multiple values for a date then the value returned in the SELECT is pretty random, so returning it is pretty useless Basic SQL is you should have all the non aggregate values in the GROUP BY clause when grouping.